# Math.eval Help: Sometimes function works, sometimes not

Tags: node.js, express, math, mongoose

I am new to coding and currently developing a wep app close to a dashboard.
I am using node js, express and mongoose.

I have defined my schemas and collectign data from users.
There are some data that I wish to work with calculations.

This is my model

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    math     = require('mathjs');

//*****DATABASE CONFIG*******
// Demog Database
 var headcountSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    headct_start: Number,
    headct_end: Number,
    m_mgr: Number,
    f_mgr: Number,
    m_stf: Number,
    f_stf: Number,
    m_ops: Number,
    f_ops: Number,
    m_mru: Number,
    f_mru: Number,
    m_intl: Number,
    etc....
    created: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    user: {
      id: {
       type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
       ref: "User"
      },
     username: String
    }
    });
module.exports = mongoose.model("Headcount", headcountSchema);
```

I am using the below format for all calculations :

```
headcountSchema.virtual('totalmanager').get(function() {  
    return math.eval(this.m_mgr + this.f_mgr);
});
```

I don't understand why the above works for some code and not for other while it is the exact same format.

For example, it worked for the totalmanager it does not work for this one:

```
headcountSchema.virtual('totalintl').get(function() {  
    return math.eval(this.m_intl + this.f_intl);
});

headcountSchema.virtual('totalmru').get(function() {  
    return math.eval(this.m_mru + this.f_mru);
});
```

So when I pass it through my ejs file, nothing appears:

```
<div class="four wide column grid ui statistic">
  <div class="value">
    <%=headcounts.totalmru%>
  </div>
  <div class="label">
    Employees in Mru
  </div>
```

Furthermore, how do i process divisions? because adding "" or () unvalidates the values and nothing happens. (also, if i divide by a number, the number is red)

Comment: Did you debug your code? What are the values of properties like `this.m_intl` and `this.f_intl` when the code does not do what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Since the types of `m_mgr, f_mgr, m_mru, f_mru` are explicitly defined as a number, then you don't need to perform `math.eval()`, you can just as easily return an expression.

```
headcountSchema.virtual('totalmanager').get(function() {  
    return this.m_mgr + this.f_mgr;
});

headcountSchema.virtual('totalintl').get(function() {  
    return this.m_intl + this.f_intl;
});

headcountSchema.virtual('totalmru').get(function() {  
    return this.m_mru + this.f_mru;
});
```

The `math.eval()` function evaluates JavaScript code represented as a string. The parameters sent can be in string form.

if you are sending expression
`math.eval(2 + 2)` is the same as `math.eval(4)= 4` 
because the expression will be executed and then evaluated. so you might as well be doing `2 + 2` directly without the `math.eval()` (unless you're sending characters and strings).

Careful with the type of values being sent.

```
 math.eval('2 + 2') = 4 
 math.eval('2' + '2') = 22
 math.eval('2' + '+' + '2')= 4
 math.eval('2' + 2))= 22
```

So, I don't recommend using `math.eval()` in this scenario, unless I failed to understand the problem here. In that case, please feel free to correct me.